# use vs2017 build perl

Tags: perl, visual-studio-2017

When I build perl use microsoft vc2017, I got an error :

```
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/Module-Load-Conditional directly
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/Module-Loaded directly
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/NEXT directly
Running pm_to_blib for dist/Net-Ping directly
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/Params-Check directly
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/Perl-OSType directly
Running pm_to_blib for cpan/PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint directly
Can't copy p to scripts/p: No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 26.
Unsuccessful Makefile.PL(cpan/Pod-Checker): code=512 at ..\make_ext.pl line 
518.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “..\miniperl.exe”: 返回代码 (return code)“0x2”
Stop.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the Windows SDK, see

- Perl [ticket #133666](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133666)
- VS forum [setargv.obj is broken in the latest windows sdk](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289637/setargvobj-is-broken-in-the-latest-windows-sdk.html)

The Perl bug reporter confirmed that the bug went away after updating the SDK. Another alternative seems to be to switch from a `CFG=DebugFull` to a `CFG=Debug` build.

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance！

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: 有一个表示接受答案的按钮需要我按一下？我没有找到哪里确认这个答案。